# Dropbox API - Add Folder Overviews when creating folder

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to add a custom folder overview using Dropbox's API is this possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Dropbox API doesn't currently expose the ability to set folder overviews programmatically, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.